# How do I REMOVE the black bars from my blender intro template

Tags: python, modeling, cycles-render-engine, rendering, blender-internal-render-engine

First l'll link my blender file i'm currently working on and having issues with, It's for a school project.

The current file i'm working on:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxYGk6KFSwGqVWYzMDBrUk1mQnc/view?usp=sharing

what happens once it's done rendering:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BxYGk6KFSwGqem5YS0JMMUNoMjA

I've tried a couple of things to get rid of the ugly bars but nothing seems to work. Everyone please pitch in with your ideas I'd love to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

I rendered several images with the file provided, and the images appeared fine without black boxes. It looked fine with both CPU and CPU rendering, but you should try to change what you are rendering with.

Since it rendered fine for me, it might be worth deleting Blender and then re-downloading the newest stable version.

Comment: I can also render images without these boxes. It's only at the end once the full render is all the way done that these black boxes will show up. I'll watch the exported video and then It will show the ugly bars after i've spent all the time rendering.

Comment: I will try re-installing blender though

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out! To everyone with this issue I've fixed it. I'll list everything you can do in Blender to hopefully get rid of those nasty black bars.

Start by going to the tab on the right hand side.

Click meta data and uncheck stamp if it's checked.

Next scroll down on that right hand tab to where it says post processing and unchecked all of those boxes.

Now go to the top of that right hand box and click the little world icon, go down to the surface tab click the image icon and delete both the black bars after that re-select whatever your background texture was.

Do the same thing as before except now instead of the world icon click on the checkered board icon.

Next go to the top of the blender window where it probably says default for you and instead go to the composting window.

Once you're there you should see and bunch of squares connected.

Find the squares that have something to do with black bars.

All you need to do to them is press the x on both of them so that it will no longer display the black bars, that's it!

Comment if this helped you, if you had issues also comment and I'll try to help you out.

Comment: Please explain that a little better. i want to do this also but i have no idea what you are talking about. please take screenshots

Comment: Get familiar with blender first and then you'll know what I'm talking about.

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm suuuper late to this thread but just any case anyone stumbles upon it, for me it was because of a Gaussian blur node in compositing, all I had to do was check the gamma box on the blur node and the black squares went completely away. I also recommend turning up your sampling if that doesn't work.